# Swift protocols and polymorphism

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to get this code to work

```
protocol Shootable
{
    func shoot ()
}

protocol Shooter
{
    var weapon:Shootable { get set }
}

class Gun:Shootable
{
    func shoot() {

    }

    func someOtherMethod()
    {

    }
}

class Player:Shooter
{
    var weapon:Gun

    init ()
    {
        weapon = Gun()
        weapon.someOtherMethod()
    }
}
```

But the compiler tells me that Player does not conform to the Shooter protocol. I assume this is because the Player weapon var is of type Gun, not Shootable, even if Gun implements Shootable.

But then I changed this and now it works:

```
protocol Shooter
{
    typealias Weapon:Shootable
    var weapon:Weapon { get set }
}
```

And I have no idea why. I thought typealiases just give another name to a type, I wasn't aware of this kind of ability...

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: If you declare weapon in your Player class as Shootable as in the protocol, and change the line containing someOtherMethod() in init to (weapon as Gun).someOtherMethod(), it will work. Although, I don't have an explanation why it does work with typealias.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to do that cast to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK `typealias` inside a `protocol` declaration is something like declaring a *generic* type. Using a *protocol* type in a declaration is declaring you will use it just for what the protocol declares.

Your first example would work in case you write:

```
class Player:Shooter
{
    var weapon:Shootable

    init ()
    {
        weapon = Gun()
        /* weapon.someOtherMethod()
        Can't use it 'cause weapon is strictly a Shootable, thus it is not meant to have any other methods than shoot()
        */
    }
}
```

Your second example works since you declare a *generic* type inside the protocol and require it to be a type that conforms to `Shootable`. Your modification makes use of type inference, thus it could be more clear the following rewriting of your second example:

```
class Player:Shooter
{
    typealias Weapon = Gun
    var weapon:Weapon

    init ()
    {
        weapon = Gun()
        weapon.someOtherMethod()
    }
}
```

Here I explicitly declare that the *generic* protocol type alias `Weapon` is `Gun` (and since it conforms to `Shootable` all is ok). In your example, this is implicitly inferred by the compiler since there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Maybe a simpler way to see why your first example doesn't work is thinking of declaring an array of `Shootable`: `var sh = [Shootable]()`. All you can legitimately do with the elements of that array is call `shoot()`. Thus you can add a `Gun` to that array, but you can't use it as something different form a Shootable while using it in the _scope_ of that array elements.

Comment: I understand why the first example doesn't work. I think it could work, though, if the compiler was smart enough to know Gun is Shootable. Actually something similar will definitely work on Objective-C. About the second example, I think I was mixing typealias Weapon:Shootable with typealias Weapon = Shootable. The former working kind of like a constrained generic and the latter just renaming a type.

Comment: Since nobody has 5 years of experience using Swift, and it is still in evolution, take my opinions as _first impressions_. With Objective-C was quite common the use of _protocols_ to _extend_ a class. In Swift we have `extension`, thus I think that `protocol` is going to take a quite different _use case_. In the end, I suspect that `protocol` will have quite different meanings on Obj-C and Swift. Your _type design_ will be much much more relevant in Swift since it can be considered _strictly typed_